# Nested for loops to search list contents in a CSV

Tags: python, string, list, csv, caesar-cipher

Been pulling my hair on this one for a while (and assuming my order/logic is off)

I have a csv file (words.csv) which has a list of thousands of words
I have a caeser cipher which is giving me a list of all of the possible permutations of a sentence and storing it in another variable (decodedformats) which I am stripping into just words as (pureword)

*What I would like to do is:
Search in the words.csv file for my words and if they exist in there, print them out as they are

*What I am currently getting is:
The words are searching and matching, however they are ordered alphabetically based on the words.csv file
This is problematic as the order of the final message is then wrong...

e.g. I get the message output as `"apple hello tattoo yellow"` instead of `"hello tattoo apple yellow"`

Any ideas?

Code:

words.csv file is like:

ORDERED Alphabetically

```
    apple,
    hello,
    tattoo,
    yellow,
```

purewords list is like:

ORDERED randomly based on user input

```
[hello,tattoo,apple,yellow,ifmmp,ubuupp,bqqmf,zfmmpx,jgnnq,vcvvqq,crrng,agnnqy]
```

```
def seekanddecrypt():

    results=[]
    pureword=[words for segments in pureword for words in segments.split()]
    print(pureword)
    with open('words.csv') as words:
    reader = csv.reader(words)
    #updated per Thomas answer below           
        for row in reader:
            for x in pureword:
                if x in row:
                    print('Found the word: {}'.format(row))
                    results.append(row)
    print("Your message contains the words: ", results)


        #working attempt
        for row in reader:
            if row[0] in pureword:
                print('Found the word: {}'.format(row))
                results.append(row)
        print("Your message contains the words: ",results)
```

Answer (score 0):

The order is not correct. You are reading your text several times, each time checking only the next word in your "pureword" list.

```
def seekanddecrypt():

    results=[]
    pureword=[words for segments in pureword for words in segments.split()]
    print(pureword)
    with open('words.csv') as words:
        reader = csv.reader(words)
        #my other attempt for review            
        for row in reader:
            for x in pureword:
                if x in row:
                    print('Found the word: {}'.format(row))
                    results.append(row)
    print("Your message contains the words: ", results)
```

Comment: Thank you! So while that does work, I have the same issue in that the words.csv is sorted alphabetically so the words are now coming out in the order of the csv file not in the order of the purewords list

Comment: Ich think it would be easier if you give a short example of your text and then give an example of how you would like your output to look like.